# How to implement recursive mutex with timeout in the OS X kernel?

Tags: multithreading, macos, timeout, driver, mutex

I'm porting a windows device driver to Mac OS X.  The windows code uses KMUTEX.  This is a recursive lock that can be acquired multiple times by the same thread.  Other threads must wait to acquire it, but the acquisition will fail if the timeout occurs.

The I/O Kit's IORecursiveLock doesn't do timeouts.  I can use BSD locks or Mach locks.  The BSD part of the kernel offers condition variables with msleep() and wakeup().

I'm not clear if a condition variable will do what I want.

sem_timedwait(3) on BSD is in userspace.

Keith Shortridge provides a [userspace set_timedwait implementation](https://github.com/attie/libxbee3/blob/master/xsys_darwin/sem_timedwait.c).  One thread calls sem_wait() while another thread that sends a signal to the first if a timeout occurs.

I could port Shortridge's code to the kernel but I don't want to risk screwing it up.  Google yields no other insight.  Can you give me a clue?

Comment: These days, Xcode seems to support **std::recursive_timed_mutex**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might be helpful, by the documentation this has what you need, maybe the method wait_result_tlck_mtx_sleep_deadline:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/synchronization/synchronization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH218-BEHJDFCA